# Access Data From One Model In Another In .NET Core MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have an Employee model as so:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Name must be between 5 and 30 characters.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*$")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Direct Contact")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid contact number. Must be 10 digits.")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Personal Cell")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid contact number. Must be 10 digits.")]
        public string Phone2 { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid fax number. Must be 10 digits.")]
        public string Fax { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Personal Email")]
        public string Email2 { get; set; }
    }
```

The employee data can be viewed in a table at /employees/

And then I am trying to create a Project model (which can be viewed at /projects/). Basically, when viewing a list of projects, one of the categories in it's table will be a project contact. So, I want to be able to link one of the employee names as the project contact.

This is my Project model:

```
public class Project
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Employee")]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
```

Am I going about this the right way? I can't seem to figure out how to properly link the two tables so that I can access the employee's name from the project view.

- edit -

I am thinking that the way I have it, when loading data into the Project table, I can add the EmployeeID to be whatever the employee's ID is in the Employee table. Then I could properly access it? Am I right in thinking that?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I going about this the right way? I can't seem to figure out how to properly link the two tables so that I can access the employee's name from the project view.

You can do as follows:

```
Employee employee =  _context.Projects.Include(p => p.Employee).FirstOrDefault(empId);
```

Now in the View you can access the `Employee's Name` as follows:

```
@Model.Employee.Name
```

For more details: [Loading Related Data in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading)

Comment: So going this route, I don't need to add anything about Employee's to my Project model?

Comment: Yes! You don't need to do anything more!

Comment: Thank you. Would I add this to my ProjectsController? I would also remove the EmployeeID Foreign key, and the virtual Employee from my model?

Comment: Yes! In the method that will render project view!

Comment: So I made my project model with these fields: Id, ProjectName, and DueDate. 
So now I would add your line of code to the ProjectsController in the index method, right? I don't quite understand how I would get a specific employee that corresponds to a certain project.Wouldn't I need a field in one of my models linking the two together?

Answer (score 0):

When displaying lists of details I would recommend adopting view model classes to represent just the data you need to display and the key(s) needed to identify them. Passing EF Entities to views as models will lead to performance and serialization issues, as well as potential vulnerabilities if entities are passed back from the view to the controller. The performance hits come from having to either eager load a lot more data from the database than you need, or resulting lazy load calls when a serializer touches references.

Instead, if you use a view model such as:

```
[Serializable]
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```

then your Project list uses `IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel>` as it's model (or a wrapper view model containing an `IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel>`).

To return the viewmodels from EF you leverage `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo<T>` methods.  For example with `Select`

```
var projects = context.Projects.Where(x => /* criteria */)
    .Select(x => new ProjectViewModel
    {
        ProjectId = x.Id,
        ProjectName = x.ProjectName,
        DueDate = x.DueDate,
        EmployeeName = x.Employee.Name
    }).ToList();
```

If you use Automapper then conventions would take care of most of that, leaving you with:

```
var projects = context.Projects.Where(x => /* criteria */)
    .ProjectTo<ProjectViewModel>()
    .ToList();
```

... at most maybe needing config to handle "Id".

The major benefit of this approach over `.Include` is that the SQL generated is a lot more efficient, and the data over the wire is more compact.

Using the ViewModel your SQL SELECT statement would look roughly like:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.ProjectName, p.DueDate, e.Name FROM Projects p INNER JOIN Employees e ON p.EmployeeId = e.Id /* WHERE criteria on p */;
```

Using the entities with Include the statement would be more like:

```
SELECT p.*, e.* FROM Projects p INNER JOIN Employees e ON p.EmployeeId = e.Id /* WHERE criteria on p */
```

The latter selects *all* columns from both joined tables. In simple examples like this it doesn't seem to be that much, but as systems grow and the # and size of tables increase, it adds up really fast.  Why query all columns from employee if you only need their name?
The real risk is if lazy loading starts getting involved. in that case you start hitting situations like:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Projects p /* WHERE criteria on p */
SELECT e.* from Employees e WHERE Id = 22
SELECT e.* from Employees e WHERE Id = 19
SELECT e.* from Employees e WHERE Id = 121
SELECT e.* from Employees e WHERE Id = 104
SELECT e.* from Employees e WHERE Id = 11
// ...
```

If the Projects query returns 20 projects there will be up to 20 queries for each and every referenced entity on Project. (whether you need the data or not) Lazy load properties will query the context when they are accessed. When a parent entity is serialized, the serializer will access each property, triggering a lazy load 1 parent at a time. (Many orders worse in performance than using `Include`)  This can result in serialization errors when you have cyclic references. (A references a B, and B references it's A)

As a general rule, even though many Microsoft examples show sending Entities to MVC views, don't send Entities to views; Use plain 'ol C# view models.

Answer (score 0):

When displaying a list of details you need to use a ViewModel (ProjectDetailsViewModel for example) instead of using the EF entities, this will avoid serializations issues.

Instead of using `.Include` for linking the project entity like below:

```
var employee =  _context.Projects.Include(p => p.Employee).FirstOrDefault(employeeId);
```

Use a ProjectDetailsViewModel like below:

```
[Serializable]
public class ProjectDetailsViewModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email{ get; set; }
}
```

And do a projection instead (this will generate a more optimized `T-SQL` and resolve serialization issues)

```
var projects = context.Projects.Where(x => /* filter_criteria */)
    .Select(x => new ProjectDetailsViewModel
    {
        ProjectId = x.Id,
        ProjectName = x.ProjectName,
        DueDate = x.DueDate,
        EmployeeName = x.Employee.Name,
        Phone = x.Employee.Phone,
        Email = x.Employee.Email
    }).ToList();
```

And finnaly in your mvc controller do this:

```
return View(projects);
```

[EF Documentation - How to create a Web API application that uses Entity Framework for database persistence.](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-4)

[Increasing the Performance of Entity Framework with Projection Queries](https://developingsoftware.com/entity-framework-projection-queries/)

[Read related data with EF in an ASP.NET MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: @burgoyne, does this resolve your issue ? let me know if still have an issue.